# Running command line tools inside of a Java program

Tags: java, command-line, junit

Hello StackOverflow Community,

I have this `JUnit` Tests that need to run a Server with the command `mvn exec:java`, and I need to delete the contents of a directory before the tests are executed. Otherwise, the `JUnit` test will fail. Is there any way I can include these steps into my source code?

Ejay

Comment: which server you need to run? it is possible to deploy in most of the server using just java api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use JUnit's @BeforeClass notation which will be called before the first test starts to clean up the target directory. You should also use the commons-io library avoid unnecessary coding.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;


public class DeleteDirectoryTest {
    private static final String DIRECTORY_PATH = "C:/TEMP";

    @BeforeClass
    public static void cleanUp() throws IOException {
        FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File(DIRECTORY_PATH));
    }

    @Test
    public void doSomeTest() {
        // Test code goes here
   }
}
```

Comment: This works, accept that I need to keep the directory. I just want its contents to be cleared. Also, how do I run another java program inside a java program?

Answer (score 1):

You can place a [recursive delete](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-delete-directory-in-java/) for your directory in your JUnit '@BeforeClass' init method.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean emptyDir(File dir) {
    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to execute commands from java applications